# WordPress Login/register with Facebook but with another username and password

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-login

I'm working on a WordPress site and I want the users to be able to register/login with Facebook but later on using a new Username and Password. Later on when the user login using Facebook, the user is logged in with that username and password. Exactly like Twitch.com has.

Does anyone know how this could be done? I know that there are multiple Facebook Login plugins for Wordpress, but I don't think there are any that let you have Username and Password that is independent of Facebook.